# Django + React js not able to render homepage correctly

Tags: python, reactjs, django, typescript

I am trying to create a web application with Django and Reactjs.
My goal is to create a homepage with username and password prompt and a submit button. When I run the program the webpage is rendering blank page and the expected behavior is to show username and password form on the webpage written in typescript.It shows a blank page with following response

```
prasku@Praskus-Air nekikx_main % python3 manage.py runserver  
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 25, 2023 - 08:22:11
Django version 4.2.1, using settings 'nekikx_main.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

[25/May/2023 08:22:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 634
[25/May/2023 08:22:15] "GET /static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[25/May/2023 08:22:15] "GET /static/js/index.js HTTP/1.1" 200 295
[25/May/2023 08:22:15] "GET /static/js/test.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1175
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]

urlpatterns += static('/static/', document_root='frontend/build/static')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

**home.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Include React and other dependencies -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Placeholder for React component -->
  <div id="react-container"></div>
  <!-- Include the main.js bundle -->
  <script src="{% static 'js/index.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/test.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import Loginform from '/Users/prasku/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Codebase/Nekikx/Nekikx/nekikx_main/frontend/pages/homepage/LoginForm'

console.log('Rendering Loginform...');

// Render the Homepage component
ReactDOM.render(<LoginForm />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

**LoginForm.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './LoginForm.scss';

const LoginForm: React.FC = () => {
  
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleUsernameChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
  };
  
  const handlePasswordChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setPassword(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Perform form submission logic here
    console.log('Submitted:', username, password);
  };

  return (
    <form className="login-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="username"
          value={username}
          onChange={handleUsernameChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={handlePasswordChange}
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Log In</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

1. I am using LoginForm function in index.js to inject html code into react-container when it runs
2. I have compiled this LoginForm.tsx to javascript using **tsc** command
   and referenced the same the resultant .js file in home.html

I am confused if both step1 and step2 are needed or only one of them is needed

either ways n ot sure what is going wrong but when I inspect element it shows following errors in my test.js

[image]

my project structure is as shown below

[image]
can some please help what I am missing here.